# Expandable sidenav using a draggable cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a resizable sidenav. I have three sections and using flexbox and percentage width to define the initial size. I'm unable to get the resize functionality to work.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RohithKasula/pen/LYaEmrO)

In the javascript code I'm resetting the width of the sidenav to a the pixel amount. Does that override the percentage width? What is the best way to set initial width but have ability to resize?

```js
var resizer = document.querySelector(".resizer"),
        sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

      function initResizerFn(resizer, sidebar) {
        // track current mouse position in x var
        var x, w;

        function rs_mousedownHandler(e) {
          x = e.clientX;

          var sbWidth = window.getComputedStyle(sidebar).width;
          w = parseInt(sbWidth, 10);

          document.addEventListener("mousemove", rs_mousemoveHandler);
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", rs_mouseupHandler);
        }

        function rs_mousemoveHandler(e) {
          var dx = e.clientX - x;

          var cw = w + dx; // complete width

          if (cw < 700) {
            sidebar.style.width = `${cw}px`;
          }
        }

        function rs_mouseupHandler() {
          // remove event mousemove && mouseup
          document.removeEventListener("mouseup", rs_mouseupHandler);
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", rs_mousemoveHandler);
        }

        resizer.addEventListener("mousedown", rs_mousedownHandler);
      }

      initResizerFn(resizer, sidebar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <div class="bg-gray-300 h-full flex">
      <div id="sidebar" class="bg-red-300 w-1/5 relative">1
        <div id="resizer" class="w-3 top-0 right-0 cursor-col-resize absolute bg-gray-600 h-full"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-green-300 w-3/5">2</div>
      <div class="bg-blue-600 w-1/5">3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `resizer` and `sidebar` are IDs, not classes. In query selector, you select them by `#resizer`, not `.resizer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector: you are using an ID in the HTML but, in your JavaScript query selector, you are using the class selector.

Change to this and it will work:

`var resizer = document.querySelector("#resizer"), var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");`